# How do I find the power factor and the equivalent inductivity value for this given scheme?

Tags: parallel, series, inductive

My exam is in 2 days and I just can't figure this thing out. I have the following scheme:

[image]

First I was asked to find out the impedance, resistance and reactance of the dipole given below. This is what I found out:

Z = 40 + j7 [Ohm]
R = 40 [Ohm]
X = +7 [Ohm].

**Now I need to find out the equivalent value of inductivity for this whole scheme. I know that for parallel circuits the equivalent inductivity value Le is:**

Le = ∑1/Lk = 1/L1 + 1/L2 + ... 1/Ln

and for the series circuits the Le value is:

Le = ∑Lk = L1 + L2 + ... +Ln.

How should I apply this formulas for this given scheme?

**For the power factor, this is what I know:**

kp = P/S.

I thought of replacing the P with R*I^2 and the S with Z*I^2, but I don't know how to get the Z value out of that complex value I found out earlier for Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the real question is what you think it is. From the sentence "find out the equivalent value of inductivity" I think you have to handle this dipole as a series R-L with impedance of 40+j7 ohms.

What values of R and L in series can have this impedance? Well R have to be 40ohm and L has to be...this was the real question I think. The answer is easy, if 
X= ω*L, then L=X/ω
Since you didn't gave us the frequency, I cant substitute for ω (ω=2*п*f), but I think you can handle this.

Your other question is almost solved by you. Yes you can replace those values, so kp = R/|Z|, where |Z| is the absolute value of the impedance you calculated, so |Z|=sqrt(R^2 + X^2)

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed the X= ω*L formula and that made it all so confusing. I managed to solve it, thank you!